# Angular nested HTTP call without using success/failure block

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

Here createSampleUser service can give success/error response from the server. but I want to call getUsers service after createSampleUser service call.
as I'm not using here next, error block... then why should I write these 2/3 lines of code.
is there any way to call nested calls without checking the success/error response from the first service call?

```
getUsers() {
        this.userService.createSampleUser({ fName: 'surendra', lName: 'tarai' })
            .subscribe(
                next => { },
                error => { },
                () => {
                    this.users$ = this.userService.getUsers('BLR');
                }
            );
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [switchMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap):

```js
this.userService.createSampleUser({ fName: 'surendra', lName: 'tarai' })
    .pipe(switchMap(() => this.userService.getUsers('BLR')))
    .subscribe(users => ...)
```

Edit:

```js
const createUser$ = this.userService.createSampleUser({ fName: 'surendra', lName: 'tarai' });
const handlingError = catchError(err => of(err); // guarantee flow continuity
const getUsers$ = this.userService.getUsers('BLR');
const stream$ = createUser$.pipe(handlingError, concatMap(() => getUsers$);

stream$.subscribe();
```

Notice that the stream$ subscription will emit only the result of getUsers$, if you want to get the events of all 'sub-streams', use [concat](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/concat) instead [concatMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/concatMap).

Comment: here if createSampleUser gives any 5** series error, then the getUsers method isn't getting invoked.
I want to just call createSampleUser service before getUsers...
no matter whether createSampleUser service gives error or success

Comment: This I can achieve using subscribe => complete block. But your edited code is is very long than my initial code. Looking for short and sweet solution

Comment: yeah, i got it, but the point is that at the end we will need to make an only one subscription with my edited code, anyway, i respect your opinion.

Comment: I marked your answer is correct, because it works as expected... but I suggest you share some short coed if possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `switchMap` for this.

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
....
getUsers() {
        this.userService.createSampleUser({ fName: 'surendra', lName: 'tarai' })
            .pipe(switchMap(sampleUser => this.userService.getUsers('BLR')))
            // .subscribe(); You have to subscribe to this stream. If this is a service,
            // I would subscribe from the component. If it's a component, 
           //then keep the subscribe and do something with it
    }
```